# fixed effects regression with felm

Tags: r, regression, fixed, effects

I am wondering why my fixed effects regression does not work.

My Code is the following:

```
sfeL=felm(sätzegesp~TTRverf,spieler|0|0, data=datregT)
```

`sätzegesp` is a vector if numbers, `TTRverf` is a dummy-variable and the fixed effect variable `spieler` is a vector of numbers indicating the ID of each person.

Unfortunately, I get the error

> operators are only possible for numeric, logical or complex types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with `felm()`, but usually we use something like `y ~ x1 + x2 + .. + xn` as formula, not `y ~ x1, x2, ... xn`. That might be the problem. You can see it in exampes in the documentation of the lfe package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lfe/lfe.pdf).

So try to use

```
sfeL <- felm(sätzegesp ~ TTRverf + spieler|0|0, data= datregT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `|` instead of `,`:

```
sfeL=felm(sätzegesp~TTRverf | spieler | 0 |0, data=datregT)
```